# Fortran 90 - segmentation fault

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am making a program that converts a decimal integer into its binary representation. Here is my code:

```
program test
implicit none
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: binary
integer :: decimalnum, i, initvalue

print*, "Enter decimal number to convert: "
read*,initvalue

decimalnum = initvalue
i = 0

do while (decimalnum > 0)
    if (MOD(decimalnum,2)==0) then
        binary(i) = 0                  ! this is as far as the program executes up to 
        decimalnum = decimalnum / 2
        i = i + 1
    else if (MOD(decimalnum,2)==1) then
        binary(i) = 1
        decimalnum = (decimalnum -1) / 2
        i = i + 1
    end if
end do
end program test
```

At the marked point, it returns the error `Segmentation fault` and exits with code 139.

Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to a `debug`? such gdb

Comment: No, I don't know how to use one.

Comment: I don't really know much about Fortran, but I just looked up 'allocatable' and it looks like you still need an 'allocate' statement to actually reserve space.

Comment: I changed that line to be `allocate(binary(i) = 0)` but the compiler returned `syntax error in allocate statement`

Comment: Looks like you have to allocate the whole thing at once--no simple way to allocate additional memory as you need it.

Comment: Also: arrays start with the index 1.

Comment: Yeah, the initial index of 0 is going to kill your code.  BTW, FORTRAN 90 does have a reallocate function, but it takes a pointer as an argument.  Probably don't want to go there for this application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so this is probably awful form, <strike>and certainly bad runtime (it copies the array for every single bit)</strike>, but here's what I came up with. It seems to work.

```
  program test
      implicit none
      integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: binary
      integer :: decimalnum, i, initvalue, curSize, curBit


      print*, "Enter decimal number to convert: "
      read*,initvalue

      decimalnum = initvalue
      i = 1
      ALLOCATE ( binary(1) )
      curSize = 1

      DO WHILE (decimalnum > 0)
        IF (i > curSize ) THEN
            curSize = curSize * 2
            CALL expandArray( curSize, i-1 )
        END IF

        IF (MOD(decimalnum,2)==0) then
            binary(i) = 0                  ! this is as far as the program executes up to 
            decimalnum = decimalnum / 2
            i = i + 1
        ELSE IF (MOD(decimalnum,2)==1) then
            binary(i) = 1
            decimalnum = (decimalnum -1) / 2
            i = i + 1
        END IF

      end do
      PRINT*, binary


  CONTAINS
      SUBROUTINE expandArray( newSize, oldSize )
          IMPLICIT NONE
          INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: temp
          INTEGER :: j, newSize, oldSize
          ALLOCATE( temp(newSize) )
          DO j=1,oldSize
              temp(j) = binary(j)
          END DO
          DEALLOCATE (binary)
          ALLOCATE( binary(newSize) )
          DO j=1,oldSize
              binary(j) = temp(j)
          END DO
          DO j=oldSize+1,newSize
              binary(j) = 0
          END DO
          DEALLOCATE (temp)
      END SUBROUTINE

  END PROGRAM test
```

Comment: Note: just edited--I erroneously had binary as a parameter to expandArray instead of a global variable. For some reason it worked anyway. In any case, it's fixed now.

Comment: I agree with the author, this code is probably awful and it copies the array for every bit.  It uses features (specifically the `continue` statements) of FORTRAN77 which have been replaced with better facilities.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Tried sprucing it up a bit--better array re-allocation, got rid of do/continue. I'm still not a Fortran programmer, obviously, so edits/feedback from a pro would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to convert an integer `i` to its binary representation:

```
write(*,'(b16)') i
```

As written, this won't write any leading `0`s.  If you want the leading `0`s, try

```
write(*,'(b16.16)') i
```

Of course, the preceding code writes the binary representation to the default output unit but using Fortran's internal write capabilities I could just as easily write the bits to a character variable.  For example:

```
character(len=16) :: bits
...
write(bits,'(b16.16)') i
```

writes the binary digits of `i` into the character variable `bits`.

Now, if what you really want is to create an array of integers each representing one bit of the binary representation, then something like this

```
integer, dimension(16) :: bitarray
...
bitarray = 0
...
do ix = 1,len(bits)
    if (bits(ix:ix)=='1') bitarray(ix) = 1
end do
```

would probably work.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your crash occurs because you had allocated only 1 element for the array binary(:), and the While loop presumably had moved on to i = 2, at which point your array is index out of bounds (crash).

2) Fortran has a number of intrinsic functions that deal with bits directly.  For example,

a) Bit_Size(var) returns the number of bits in "var", so if you must use an allocatable, now you know the array size required in advance.

b) BTest(iVar, pos) returns .True. if the bit at pos in iVar is 1

For example, using the other declarations above,:

```
Integer     :: n

n = Bit_Size(decimalnum)    

If( Allocated(Binary) ) DeAllocate(Binary)          ! good practice
Allocate( Binary(1:n) )                             ! in general, should get IOStat, just in case

Binary(:) = 0

ForAll(i=1:n, Mask = BTest( decimalnum, i-1 ) ) ! remember, bit intrinsics index from 0
    Binary(i) = 1
End ForAll
```

... this is a little more efficient compared to Do and While, and may help (a little) towards smp.  The Where/EndWhere construct can be used also, but I find ForAll's a little more efficient.

c) IBits(var, pos, len) extracts the bits from var starting at pos for len number of bits, for example if you wanted to create an "explicit" binary representation, that might be one way to go.

etc etc

3) If you "really mean" convert DecimalNum to Bin, then you have (substantial) additional problems, if Dec also includes floating point Dec (i.e. Reals), since the bit representation of Reals is in terms of exponents.  I will assume that is not the case, as the code/explanation for that is much much more involved.

Finally, in Fortran, Nums are usually "signed" Nums and the leading bit is used to determine +ve (0) or -ve (1).  So if you were going in the "other" direction (Bin2Dec), then would prefer an additional arg (perhaps optional) that controls whether the result is signed or unsigned.  If unsigned, then the output var will need to be "bigger" compared to the input var (e.g. if converting unsigned 1-byt int to Fortran int, then must use at least 2-byte int (i.e. input Integer(1) must be output to an Integer(2)) etc.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, you need to have executed an allocate statement (or something which does an allocation for you under the covers) before you can define the `binary` array.  The simplest form of allocation statement would look something like `ALLOCATE(binary(10))`, which would given the `binary` array 10 elements, using the default (it can be changed for that array using the allocate statement) starting array index of 1.

Where the size of the allocation is not easily known before working with an array there are two basic approaches:

- Do two passes, the first pass of which simply counts how many elements are required, then the array is allocated, then the second pass actually does the assignment to the relevant elements.
- Allocate the array to an initial size (which may be zero), the progressively grow the array as required.

There are trade-offs associated with the decision around the approach to use associated with the relative overheads of things like allocation and the evaluation of each test when counting.

In Fortran 90 (time to move on to at least Fortran 95!), growing an allocatable array is somewhat convoluted (allocate a temporary, copy data from original to temporary, deallocate original, allocate original to new size, copy data from temporary back to resized original, deallocate temporary).  In Fortran 2003 this operation becomes trivial.

Comment: @AussieGamer: you'll struggle to find a compiler which accepts much of the additional syntax added by the 2008 revision of the language; most of the compilers on the market now implement most of Fortran 2003.